# Trying to insert Json into Neo4j

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-kafka, spring-data-neo4j

Everyone I am new to neo4j and I am trying to enter Json into Neo4j but I am getting Match statement instead of create. Earlier I tried something myself and when When I inserted Json message only as
{"name":"john","dept":"Science"}
it went without a glitch but everytime I want try to add numeric data it gets error.

```
2020-03-10 13:21:59.793  INFO 94817 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest : Thread: 
29, url: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/92, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} 
as row **MATCH** (n) WHERE ID(n)=row.nodeId SET n:`UsersInfo` SET n += row.props RETURN row.nodeId as ref,
ID(n) as id, {type} as type","parameters":{"type":"node","rows":[{"nodeId":23,"props":{"name":"raj",
"dept":"science","age":11}}]},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
```

These are my classes 
KafkaConfiguration

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Users> userConsumerFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
         config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
         config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_json");
         config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
         config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
         return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(),
                    new JsonDeserializer<>(Users.class));
        }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Users> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Users> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(userConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

KafkaConsumer class

```
Service
public class KafkaConsumer {

    @Autowired
    public Neo4jservice neo4jService;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "UsersJson", groupId = "group_id", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consume(Users users) {
        System.out.println("Consumed message: " + users);
        UsersInfo usern = new UsersInfo();
        usern.setAge(users.getAge());
        usern.setDept(users.getDept());
        usern.setId(users.getId());
        usern.setName(users.getName());
        neo4jService.saveIntoStudentsTable(usern);
    }
}
```

Neo4jService

```
@Service
public class Neo4jservice {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepo userRepo;

    public UsersInfo saveIntoStudentsTable(UsersInfo users) {
        UsersInfo usern = userRepo.save(users);
        return (usern);
    }   

}
```

UsersRepo

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepo extends Neo4jRepository<UsersInfo, Long>{

}
```

Users class

```
public class Users {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String dept;
    private Integer age;

    **getters,setters and toString method here**
}
```

Likewise UsersInfo class

```
@NodeEntity
public class Users {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String dept;
    private Integer age;

    **getters,setters and toString method here**
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by entering Json? Typically you load data with a cypher create or merge statement or with LOAD CSV or Json.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting also the `id` value of the `User` class.
This will make Spring Data Neo4j and the Neo4j Object Graph Mapper that is used for the persistence think that the entity already exists.
In this case it will `MATCH` on an existing `id(n)` and update the properties as you can see in the logs instead of `CREATE` a new node.